# Decreasing an element's opacity totally hides it with Cordova and Framework7(v1)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I want to set one of my element's back-color to a half transparent white like this:

```
background-color: #ffffff50;
```

I don't know if the problem lies specifically with Cordova or with Framework7, but when I add this CSS, the item's background gets hidden(or turns completely transparent). The only way then for me to show it is by setting the back-color to a 100% opacity.

Note: I am not using the CSS `Opacity` property. I am changing the background's opacity.
Also: I'm using v1 of Framework7.

Comment: you can use an rgba colour: `background-colour: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` the last number being the opacity - background opacity for hex values has very little support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

Comment: Hex8 is not properly supported as yet and should not be used in production. RGBA is a much better option. - Most IDEs won't recognise it - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa